# NoMethodError undefined method `stripe_customer_token'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I am setting up to cancel subscriptions from the Subscription controller, however on the action I am getting a No Method Error `` undefined method `stripe_customer_token' ``

The error points to the line `@customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(@user.stripe_customer_token)`

Subscriptions controller:

```
     def cancelsubscription
         @customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(current_user.stripe_customer_token)
         @customer.cancel_subscription()
         @current_user.subscriptionstatus = false
         current_user.save!
         UserMailer.stripe_cancellation(current_user).deliver
         flash.alert = 'Your subscription has been cancelled successfully!'
         redirect_to edit_user_registration_path
       end
end
```

Comment: Do you have a field/method called `stripe_customer_token` in User model? And where have you initialized `@user`?

Comment: `stripe_customer_token` is in the subscription model.

Comment: What is @user? Instance of which class? It should be an instance of Subscription model. Also, can you add the code where you are setting @user value.

Comment: Ah. I have to add the @user to it. Let me work on that. Thanks.

Comment: @KirtiThorat Adding `@user = current_user` still produces the error unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stripe_customer_token` is a field in `Subscription` Model.
`User` is associated to Subscription with `has_one` association.

Make sure to set the value of `@user`.

And change

```
@customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(@user.stripe_customer_token)
```

to

```
@user = ...     ## Set the value of @user
@customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(@user.subscription.stripe_customer_token)
```